# Updating user via Graph API 'must refer to service operation or an entity set'

Tags: azure-devops, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

There is a known bug with AAD B2C where resetting user password as admin for a local account locks them out

The solution was said to be to update the user instead via the Graph API so they can reset password themselves on next login

I am using the URL and format given at this link

https://msdn.microsoft.com/Library/Azure/Ad/Graph/api/users-operations#ResetUserPassword

I am trying to do this via postman but whenever I attempt to run the command i get this

```
    "code": "Request_BadRequest",
    "message": {
        "lang": "en",
        "value": "The URI 'https://graph.windows.net/[mytenant].onmicrosoft.com/directoryObjects/$/Microsoft.DirectoryServices.User/[userid]?api-version=1.6' is not valid for POST operation. For POST operations, the URI must refer to a service operation or an entity set."
```

Answer (score 0):

Beginner error, I should have been using patch, not post